# what is meaning of pgd_bad, pmd_bad, pud_bad, while converting kernel addressess?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel, arm64, page-tables

Can somebody please explain below macros in kernel page tables?

```
#define pgd_bad(pgd)            (!(pgd_val(pgd) & 2))
#define pmd_bad(pmd)            (!(pmd_val(pmd) & 2))
#define pud_bad(pud)            (!(pud_val(pud) & 2))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As originally defined in the now rather out of date (but excellent) Understanding the Linux Virtual Memory Manager `_bad()` macros determine whether a specified page table entry is **not** in a suitable state for modification.

However it turns out the macros are slightly nebulous across architectures, and might better be described in arm64 as determining whether an entry does **not** contain a reference to a page containing the table for the next level page table - see [this commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/a1c76574f345342d23836b520ce44674d23bc267) for some details.

Expanding on @Notlikethat's answer, the macros do refer to the 'table' bit, which in turn (at least in linux kernel use, there might be more detailed architecture-specific details at play) determines whether the entry's physical address refers to a huge page (64KiB - see the [arm64 memory layout doc](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.6/Documentation/arm64/memory.txt)) or not.

If we look at `pte_huge()` which determines whether a page entry refers to a huge page or not we see:

```
#define pte_huge(pte)           (!(pte_val(pte) & PTE_TABLE_BIT))
```

This indicates that if the bit is set the page size is 4KiB, if it's *cleared* it's 64KiB and therefore huge.

This leads to the conclusion that, in arm64, the `pXX_bad()` macros return true if huge pages are used.

However, the definitions you give are actually not used if huge tables are enabled :)

Looking again at the memory layout doc referenced above, it turns out that the huge page table layout uses only 2 levels. The way linux deals with architectures which have less than 4 page table levels is to 'fold in' non-existent levels into existing tables, and let the compiler remove all of the unnecessary code.

And if we look at `arch/arm64/include/asm/pgtable.h` above the `pgd_bad()` definition (on line 445 at the time of writing), we see:

```
#if CONFIG_PGTABLE_LEVELS > 3
```

And above the `pud_bad()` definition (on line 392 at the time of writing) we see:

```
#if CONFIG_PGTABLE_LEVELS > 2
```

So in fact since `CONFIG_PGTABLE_LEVELS == 2` in the huge table case, different definitions are used.

In `arch/arm64/include/asm/pgtable-types.h` we see (at line 89 at the time of writing):

```
#if CONFIG_PGTABLE_LEVELS == 2
#include <asm-generic/pgtable-nopmd.h>
#elif CONFIG_PGTABLE_LEVELS == 3
#include <asm-generic/pgtable-nopud.h>
#endif
```

So in fact definitions from `include/asm-generic/pgtable-nopmd.h` are used, which itself imports `include/asm-generic/pgtable-nopud.h`, giving us:

```
static inline int pgd_bad(pgd_t pgd)            { return 0; }
static inline int pud_bad(pud_t pud)            { return 0; }
```

And we already had:

```
#define pmd_bad(pmd)            (!(pmd_val(pmd) & 2))
```

Which means that any huge page PMD entry which has `pmd_bad()` called on it will return true. However, if you look at the commit I mentioned above, you'll see that prior to the commit, a `_bad()` returning true would result in code handling the 'section map' case, where presumably the PMD contains different metadata (I don't want to dive *too* deep here :) and separate code is used, now that's handled via `pmd_sect()` and we don't care about what `pmd_bad()` says, *if* the entry is a section map.

Looking at `arch/arm64/mm/mmu.c`, `pmd_set_huge()` (line 828 at the time of writing), it seems like huge table PMDs are set as section maps meaning that we don't need to care about `pmd_bad()` (I *may* be mistaken here, I've not looked deep or gone through with a debugger, but it seems this way.)

So it seems overall the `_bad()` case now means something different - it just indicates that a bug has resulted in some code that's meant to be handling a non-section map/huge page table entry is handling a huge section map page table entry, which clearly needs to be indicated.

**NOTE:** Since I created an account just to reply here, I don't have enough reputation to give more links :) a kind person with more rep might want to add links where they make sense to, e.g. the 'at line XX at the time of writing' entries.)

Answer (score 1):

In the ARMv8 64-bit page table descriptor format, for a valid (i.e. bit 0 set) level 0, 1, or 2 entry, bit 1 discriminates between table and block (hugepage) entries. Thus these macros will return false if the given entry has bit 1 set, indicating the expected table entry, or true if it is clear indicating a block or invalid entry. The `p*d_val()` accessors are simply wrappers for [optionally enforcing type-safety](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm64/include/asm/pgtable-types.h).